# How can i see my exact burnout/mana in ars magica?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-yogscast-complete-pack

Well i have been playing yogscast complete with a friend of mine, he has been guiding me through Thaumcraft and Blood magic. I then decided to start learning a bit of ars magica. I got to level 7 but i can't see my maximum mana or burnout and when i was watching a video of someone play it they had the numbers visible. How can i get them to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command `/amuicfg`, which allows you to see mana and burnout in many different ways. To exit the menu press ESC.

Comment: Thankyou, worked and now i can see everything  :D